# What is やってけんのかな？

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

What does the けん mean in this sentence? Is this a dialect?

> やって**けん**のかな

Comment: Some context would be helpful... What's the situation? Who's talking to who? For now it looks like a very informal "やってくれるのかな" or "やってくれへんのかな" if the speaker uses Kansai dialect. It would mean "I wonder if he/she will do that for me"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

やっていけるのかな changed to やっていけんのかな and it changed to やってけんのかな.

Some contexts are necessary to explain the meaning.