# Why is the て-form being used before ん？

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

In the following sentence:

> 誰｛だれ｝探｛さが｝してんの

What is the grammatical reason for  探｛さが｝す to be used in て-form **before ん**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

誰探して**ん**の is a contracted form of 誰探して**る**の, which in turn is a contracted form of 誰(を)探して**いる**の ("Who are you looking for?", notice the progressive form). More generally:

- ている contracts to てる. (See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8F-for-preparation-conjugation-and-nuance/18159#18159))
- **`/r/ + vowel` before a /n/ consonant can turn into ん** in casual speech. (Do not confuse this ん as explanatory-の.)

Examples:

- わか**ら**ない。 → わか**ん**ない。
  waka**ra**nai → waka**n'**nai
- 見て**る**の。　→　見て**ん**の。
  mite**ru**no → mite**n'**no
- 寝**る**なよ。　→　寝**ん**なよ。
  ne**ru**nayo → ne**n'**nayo
- しゃべ**り**なさい。 → しゃべ**ん**なさい。
  shabe**ri**nasai → shabe**n'**nasai
- 食べら**れ**ないよ。 → 食べら**ん**ないよ。
  tabera**re**naiyo → tabera**n'**naiyo

Related:

- [What are the rules for substituting の with ん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5780/5010)
- [わからない vs わかね in My Boss My Hero](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13069/5010)
- [Readings of「乗んなかった」 and 「また来なね」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38205/5010)
- [What is やってけんのかな？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29867/5010)

**EDIT:** By extension, るんだ/るんじゃ can contract to んだ/んじゃ (informal and slangy).

- 何して**るん**だ。 → ×何してんんだ。 → 何して**ん**だ。
- 面白くな**るん**だよ。 → ×面白くなんんだよ。 → 面白くな**ん**だよ。
- 見**るん**じゃねえ。 → ×見んんじゃねえ。 → 見**ん**じゃねえ。

Comment: "るんだ/るんじゃ can contract to るんだ/るんじゃ" -- don't you mean to remove the る from the contracted forms?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score -2):

According to the site below, it is the dialect of Osaka.
[https://www.weblio.jp/content/てん?edc=OSAKA](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93?edc=OSAKA)

Examples:

Osaka: なにしてん
Tokyo: なにをしているの

Osaka: なにしとん
Tokyo: なにをしておるの

Comment: でも「誰探してんの」「なにしてんの」は標準語でフツーに言いますよね。