# What does "目ついてんのか" mean?

Tags: translation

I've seen it on several sites now like this one. https://bokete.jp/boke/52796390

Seems like some sort of insult to me. I'm not sure what ついてん means here.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "(顔に)目(が)ついてるのか". る change to ん , which is a colloquial way. 目ついてんのか implies that you seem not to have eyes and seem to be able to see nothing. This phrase is very rude and used to revile someone. For example, when a person bumped into someone on the street, he may say it with anger, then they may fight.

Comment: So literally something like "Do you have eyes in your head?"

Comment: Yes, that is a rude way of it.

Comment: More naturally, "What are you, blind or something?"