# Japanese N1 practice questions help

Tags: jlpt, reading-comprehension, spoken-language

Taken from question 4 and 5 of this URL:
https://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n1-listening-exercise-5/

QUESTION 4:
The audio starts with:  あ～ぁ、やってらんないよなあ。 I usually feel pretty confident with spoken Japanese contractions, but I can't make heads or tails of what this statement is.  What is "やってらんない" short for?

QUESTION 5:

The statement and three possible responses are:

この料理、二人分にしちゃ物足りないよね。

1 うん、食べた気がしないね。

2 ひとり分で十分だったよね。

3 本当、食べきれないよ。

The correct answer is 1, although I'm confused why 2 wouldn't be the better answer.

My translations are: This meal wouldn't be enough for two people.  1: Yeah, but I'm not feeling hungry.  2:  It was plenty for one.  3:  I really can't eat it all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**QUESTION 4**

やってらんない is short for やっていられない. やっていられない becomes やってられない, which becomes やってらんない ([`re`-to-`n`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010)). But since this is a colloquial and slangy expression, we see this almost always in the contracted form. Variations include やってられるか, やってられっか, やってられん, やってらんねー, etc. It's a set phrase meaning "I can't stand it anymore", "I've had enough", "I'm so tired of this", etc.

**QUESTION 5**

The options actually mean:

> 1: Yeah, I don't feel like I ate anything.
>   2: (Ordering just) one serving/dish would've been enough.
>   3: I really can't eat it all.

So 2 and 3 mean they ordered too much. Here 1人分 ("one person's worth/portion") is the same as 1人前 ("one serving (of food)"). "It was plenty for one" would be something like 1人なら十分だったけどね.

Comment: 「人分なら十分だったけどね.」wouldn't this be better translated as "It would be enough for one person, though" when following the previous line?

Comment: @user26484 My mistake, I should not have included 分.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even catch that; I was more curious on changing the よね, けどね portion. My understanding was that the second answer would've been correct if it had けどね instead (not よね).

Comment: @user26484 1人分なら十分だった or 1人分で十分だった means "ordering one serving would've been enough" and 1人なら十分だった means "It would've been enough if I were alone". Here they are saying 物足りない even though they ordered two servings, so only the latter fits the context. けどね is optional.

Comment: I somehow thought of it as "if it was a portion for one person [if it was for one person]." I didn't read your correction carefully and didn't notice that 分 was removed. Oops ><