# How is おあがん working in this sentence

Tags: words

I have been reading this [book](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000361/files/58199_69586.html) and I came across this paragraph, which is aa conversation between two people:

『では、一つどういうわけでわたしがその愛のお蔭で、ああいう事件をし出かしたか、あなたにお聞かせしましょう。』

『どうぞ、もしあなたに苦痛でなかったら。』

『いや、わたしは黙っているのが苦痛なんです。まあお茶を**おあがん**なさい‥‥それとも、あまり濃すぎますか？』

いかにもお茶はビールのようだったが、わたしは一杯飲み干してしまった。ちょうどこのとき車掌が通り過ぎた。彼は毒々しげな眼つきで、それをじっと見送っていた。やがて車掌が出て行ってから、ようやく話を始めた。

My translation regarding this part would be:

『いや、わたしは黙っているのが苦痛なんです。まあお茶を**おあがん**なさい‥‥それとも、あまり濃すぎますか？』

No, My silence is painful. Well the tea .... なさい, or is it too strong?

I have tried looking for the meaning of that word, but I have been unable to do so.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/9831

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but I think in this context a better translation of いや、わたしは黙っているのが苦痛なんです would be something like "No, it would be painful for me *not* to tell you." (And by the way, thanks for including so much context, and the link.)

Answer (score 2):

This is just お茶をお上がりなさい written in a way that reflects the speaker's  speech patterns.

So your translation is nearly right: "In any case, please have some tea. Or... is it too strong for you?"

Comment: So in this case: 「あなたどうしたのです、正気におなんなさい！ the same thing is happening, の？　The sentence after the comma in other words would be: 正気におなりなさい！

Comment: Correct: that is, “what’s happened to you, please come to your senses!”