# What does the word「なさんな」mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases, manga

The person said the following sentence after he was told to hurry up doing something.

Here is the full sentence containing the word.

> そう あわて**なさんな**　おっちゃん まだまだ日は高いじゃござんせんか!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> あわてなさんな ≂ あわてるな "No hurry" "Don't panic"

なさんな is a contracted pronunciation of なさるな.
なさるな consists of: literary honorific 「なさる」 + negative imperative final particle 「な」.