# what grammatical structures in this word 考えなさんな?

Tags: grammar, slang

「そう難しく考えなさんな、佳織ちゃんよ」

please help to define grammatical structures in this word 考えなさんな

なさ　looks like なさい（imperative). てんな　is ているな　(continuative negative imperative) , but here is no て

so what is this ? slang contraction for 考えているな　(continuative negative imperative)　？

P.S. solved, 考えなさんな it is contraction for 考えなさるな - polite negative emperative

Comment: Is this it? http://www.edewakaru.com/archives/9757961.html and https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=22282

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80985/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なさんな is basically a shortened form of なさるな. なさる is an honorific version of する, and な is a negative imperative particle. It follows [this generic pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010). There is no progressive -teiru in this sentence.

> そう難しく考えなさんな
> (Please) don't think about it too hard.

But please note that uncontracted なさるな sounds like a samurai in historical dramas. We almost never say it in modern Japanese, just as we almost never say なされ (we say なさい instead). So it may be better to think なさんな is now a fixed expression, as the links in the comment section say. In general, なさんな sounds fairly colloquial and old-fashioned.