# Meaning of すん here?

Tags: grammar, japanese-to-english

I found this sentence:

```
「いやどうなんだろ遠いようで意外と近かったりすんのかな」
```

And I don't know the meaning of that すん right there. Is it a する？Or is it something ese?

Comment: Yes, it is the slurred version for する.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/9831