# What contraction is this?「何言っとんだ」

Tags: grammar, contractions, morphology

I occasionally see 何言っとんだ？ where I would expect 何言ってんだ？ but I am not sure that とん comes from ておくの. I thought [ん 縮約形 only occurred with ら行](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/30454).

> 今さら、何言っとんだ？ ([source](https://0ut0fyah00.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-3940.html))

> 何言っとんだ。ようやってると思ってたのにこれでマイナスポイントだよ。 ([source](https://mobile.twitter.com/tsboccoli/status/1296423042130874368))

> 何言っとんだ？ ([source](https://twitter.com/poke_times/status/1302803784591011840))

Comment: Perhaps it can be understood as 何を言っておるのだ?

Comment: @JimmyYang That'd make sense! Since ～ておる is 謙遜語, I thought it'd only apply to one's own action. But that does seem to be the most convincing explanation so far.