# Why use ran in 母さんは 逃げらんなかったんだって

Tags: grammar, conjugations, anime, morphology

I saw this sentence in an episode of *Attack on Titan* where a character says

> 逃げらんなかったんだって

why does the speaker say

> 逃げら**ん**なかったんだって

instead of

> 逃げらなかったんだって

what does the ん mean add to the sentence in this context

I know you can say stuff like **知らん** to mean **知らない** but this is connected to **なかった** which already makes it negative I don`t understand the use of **ん** in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

逃げる is 一段動詞, 知る is 五段動詞. So negating 知る we get 知らない⇒知らん, but that's not what's happening with 逃げる here. That's 逃げられる, the potential or passive form. Since you said this was from 進撃の巨人, I assume it's more likely potential 可能形. The original is probably:

> 逃げら**れ**なかったんだって

As for the change from 逃げられなかった⇒逃げらんなかった, see this canonical answer:

[Why is the て-form being used before ん？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/30454)