# 休ん and 違うん . I don't get if this is a verb form, conjugation, a contraction or some grammar that I still don't know

Tags: grammar, verbs, colloquial-language, slang, contractions

I found these phrases reading and didn't get if they were a verb form, conjugation or what, I neither could find them on a dictionary. I assume they are colloquial forms of speaking and this is the context of each one:

1. あんた学校どうする？念のため休んどいてもいいけど
2. 何か違うんだろうか
3. 考えんのやめよ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. 休んどいてもいい is a colloquial contraction of 休んでおいてもいい. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010). 休んで is the simple te-form of 休む, but a te-form may be "fused" with a following subsidiary verb and look different.
2. 違うんだろう is the dictionary form of the verb 違う, followed by an [explanatory-の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010), followed by だろう for inference.
3. 考えんの is a colloquial contraction of 考えるの, which is 考える with a nominalizer. See [this rule](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010).

---

Here are translations in case you need:

1. 念のため休んどいてもいいけど
   = 念のため休んでおいてもいいけど
   It's fine to have a day off just in case.
2. 何か違うんだろうか
   = 何か違うのだろうか
   I wonder, is it that something is different?
3. 考えんのやめよ
   = 考えるの(を)やめよう
   I'm gonna stop thinking (about it).

Comment: thank you! I kinda guessed the first one, but that ど instead of で lost me completely. Again, thank you.

Comment: I had some more doubts written down and they were solved thanks to that te + subsidiary verb contraction explanation you gave me.

Answer (score 2):

「休んで」of「休んでおいてもいい」 sometimes change to 「休んど」 in spoken language becuase the next Hiragana of 「休んで」 is 「お」.
「え e」drops from「休んでおいて　Yasundeoite」, so it becomes to 「休んどいて Yasundoite」in this case.